# Broadcast tv setup.

Tags: setup, broadcast, television

Hi there I'm in business and I'm looking to expand. I think there is a vast need for broadcast tv in my country  (Jamaica). So I'm exploring what it takes to get setup and all.

I want to know if there is a way to broadcast multiple channels simultaneously from one location, as in can i only have one broadcast tower and shoot more than 1 channel from that. I would like to do a entertainment, kids, news/weather channels. All advice and input are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You might also be able to get advice about this on [the Stack Exchange Electrical Engineering community](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can broadcast more than one program service (channel) from a single location. This is fairly common.

For analog over the air [(NTSC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC), you can use combiners and a broadband antenna. (See, for example, [Whitaker & Benson, 2000](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070696276) chs. 15 & 16)*

For any of the digital over the air or satellite delivery standards, [multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplex_(television)) is part of the standard.

For fiber optic delivery to a cable headend or contract uplink facility, similar multiplexing technology is available, like from [Evertz](http://www.evertz.com/solutions/transport), [Ericsson](https://www.ericsson.com/ourportfolio/products/television-and-video), and many others.

* The newer edition of this book, and many other video engineering texts, dropped the analog systems discussion because of the transition to digital in the US.